# Program to do InFile arrays

Tags: c++

I am to write a program with 6 columns to show the information for household income, SAT score, Freshman GPA, Number of Siblings, Number of hours study per week, and whether they are a binge drinker or not.  The program is to read the in data and print out the students whose income is over 100,000 and their gpa<=2.3.  I have the infile document with the c++ file.  When I go to run the program no errors, but zero output.  I am following along with the template given by my instructor.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <iomanip>  
#include <fstream>  
using namespace std;  
int main()  

{  

int IncomeArray[975];              
int SATArray[975];                  
float GPAArray[975];                
int SiblingArray[975];                         
int StudyHoursArray[975];           
int BingeDrinkerArray[975];      
int Counter = 1;                   
int Counter2 = 1;                                                          

ifstream InFile;  
InFile.open("Students"); 
while(!InFile.eof())               
{  
InFile>>IncomeArray[Counter]>>SATArray[Counter]>>GPAArray[Counter]>>
      SiblingArray[Counter]  >>StudyHoursArray[Counter]>>BingeDrinkerArray[Counter];  
++Counter;  
}  



 for(Counter2 = 1; Counter2 <= Counter; ++Counter2)  
     {  
     cout<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<showpoint;  
        if(IncomeArray[Counter2]>100000 && GPAArray[Counter2] <= 2.3)  
        {
                             cout<<IncomeArray[Counter]<<setw(5)<<SATArray[Counter]<<
                             setw(5)<<GPAArray[Counter]<<setw(3)<<SiblingArray[Counter]
                             <<setw(3)<<StudyHoursArray[Counter]<<' '<<
                             BingeDrinkerArray[Counter]<<endl;  
                    }  
              }  

InFile.close();  
return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `counter2` in the `for` loop. It is your loop variable and it should be accessed inside the loop for accesing corresponding data

```
for(Counter2 = 1; Counter2 <= Counter; ++Counter2)  
 {  
    cout<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<showpoint;  
    if(IncomeArray[Counter2]>100000 && GPAArray[Counter2] <= 2.3)  
    {
                         cout<<IncomeArray[Counter2]<<setw(5)<<SATArray[Counter2]<<
                         setw(5)<<GPAArray[Counter2]<<setw(3)<<SiblingArray[Counter2]
                         <<setw(3)<<StudyHoursArray[Counter2]<<' '<<
                         BingeDrinkerArray[Counter2]<<endl;  
     }  
 }
```

Advice : Array indexing in C starts from 0..So you are wasting array position 0 here

So better to initialize `counter` to 0 at start..start loop index `counter2` also from 0.

Comment: Still no output. I tried removing and adding back the file incase something was wrong with the .txt, that didn't help either. Thank you though :)

Comment: put checks to verify if `open` succeeded